# Linq a.Metadata.ToLower().Contains

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a problem with List of objects, which one have field for example Metadata, which is null. So when i use a.Metadata.ToLower().Contains(someText)
It shows me error, about null value. How Can I fix it ?
P.S. I see this problem first time, I tried to do the same with other List of objects which one also have null fields and it works, where can be problem ?

Comment: Welcome to SO,Post the code your tried so far.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
.Where(a => a.Metadata.ToLower().Contains(someText))
```

do

```
.Where(a => a.Metadata != null && a.Metadata.ToLower().Contains(someText))
```

Comment: assume `someText` is not empty, you can make it shorter like this `.Where(a => (a.Metadata ?? "").ToLower().Contains(someText))`

Answer (score 0):

Linq don't like null value but sometime we can't like exemple above just ignore what is null so i took habitude to cast null into the empty or minimal value.
so the value even null are cared like all other value .

have you tried a null fusion opérator in your linq query?

its : ?? operator

it will return rigth part if your data is null (in my case i return a string empty).

exemple i want sort a machine list that have some null string.

```
ListControleMachine.Sort((a1, a2) => (a1.MachineName ?? string.Empty).CompareTo(a2.MachineName ?? string.Empty));
```

you see when i sort my machine if its name is null i transform null into String.empty